# Why is props not received via links in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My Route is in App.js

```
 <Route
        path="/BlogEdit/:blogId"
        handler={BlogEdit}
        component = {() => <BlogEdit editBlog={this.editBlog}/>}
    />
```

My link is in blog.js

```
 <Link to={`/BlogEdit/${this.blogId}`}>
        <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Edit</a>
    </Link>
```

And my component where I want to access the blogId is

```
 render() {

    console.log(this.props.match.params.blogId);     // this comes out undefined
    return (
      <div className = "Editor">
      <br/><br/>


      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally changed my route to:

```
<Route
    path="/BlogEdit/:blogId"
    render={props => <BlogEdit {...props} editBlog={this.editBlog} />}
  />
```

And my link to:

```
<Link to={`/BlogEdit/${this.blogId}`}
    className="waves-effect waves-light btn">Edit
</Link>
```

And my component to:

```
render() {
const { editorState } = this.state;
const {match: { params } } = this.props;
const { blogId } = params;
console.log(blogId);

return (
  <div className = "Editor">
  <br/><br/>


);
}
```

And it Works now :)